# DatetimePicker and jquery version incompatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a working jsfiddle example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumn2u/0Ltv25o8/1334/)

according this example I am trying to write code.

my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sprSec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js'></script>

    <script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#startDateDiv').datetimepicker({
                format: 'LT'
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row-fluid main-content chose" style="padding: 20px 0 67px 0;">
    <form:form commandName="campaignBeanDto" id="addParams" method="POST">
    <div class="param-line">
            <div id="startDateDiv" class="input-append date add-params-date-div">

            <fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' var="beginDate"/>
            <form:input path="beginDate" id="startDate" name="beginDate"
                        data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" />
                            <span class="add-on">
                                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"> </i>
                            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</div>
</form:form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I start it I see just usual input.

What do I wrong?

**P.S.**

I noticed that something wrong with jquery version. If I change it on jsfiddle - it doesn't work(simple input I see) and when return it back - it doesn't work anyway.

### update

Now I have the following code:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sprSec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js'></script>

    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js'></script>

    <script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'LT'
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row-fluid main-content chose" style="padding: 20px 0 67px 0;">
    <form:form commandName="campaignBeanDto" id="addParams" method="POST">
    <div class="param-line">
            <div id="startDateDiv" class="input-append date add-params-date-div">

            <fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' var="beginDate"/>
            <form:input path="beginDate" id="startDate" name="beginDate"
                        data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" />
                           <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class=""></span>
                           </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</div>
</form:form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work too.

Comment: @learner please provid more details.  I didn't understand what mean **just removing the calendar glyphicon**

Comment: I had same issue as you are having now! I haven't got the solution for this. So I ended up removing the `calendar glyphicon` and only having the `input` ..and invoking the `datepicker` method using the input `id` when input was pressed!!!!

Comment: @learner I updated topic with corrections according your comment. It doesn't work too. Did I do somethong wrong ?

Comment: `<input id="some_id" type='text' class="form-control" />` and the `Javascript code` make this change ` $('#some_id').datetimepicker(); `..Hope you get this...what I did is added **id** to the input tag and called it using Jquery

Comment: It works better but I see **Uncaught Error: datetimepicker component should be placed within a relative positioned container** and it displays bad

Comment: This works fine for me!! can you please post the pic to imgur or some other site so that I can see it..paste the link

Comment: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/150614/ad22a87818.jpg

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the `input-group` with the icon you need to set the picker to the container div and not the input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#startDateDiv').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
});
```